# No video output or BIOS screen after Windows 10 malware

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, malware

The only way to properly explain this issue is by explaining the history behind it so sorry for the wall of text but here goes:

After being careless with some torrents I seemed to get a virus that was installing random programs and spamming pop-ups so I went ahead and restarted my computer. After restarting I noticed that I did not see a BIOS screen and that my display resolution had dropped considerably. I went into the advanced startup options and tried to reset my windows installation but after clicking on `reset` the screen would go black and I would have no video input into my monitor at all. I have tried rebooting and booting into BIOS multiple times (even though I don't see the prompt for it) but the computer always boots to the low resolution windows login page.

In an act of desperation I removed my hard drive and I still had no video input or BIOS at all. I also tried removing my video card and connecting my monitor directly to the motherboard to get integrated graphics, but that also resulted in no video input.

The only way for me to do anything was by logging into windows and trying to navigate through the jungle of spam and malware that had installed itself. I went into the windows reset prompt through there and had partial success but after windows had to restart the computer, I again found that I had no video input. After that ordeal I can't even boot into the windows login page. After starting my computer all I get is a black screen with no video whatsoever.

Does anyone have any idea whats going on or what move I should make from here ?

Comment: You've changed so many things now that it's going to be very hard to figure out what combination of things might be wrong. I'd suggest removing all hardware not needed for the system to POST (including any discrete graphics), reset the BIOS settings following your motherboard instructions, and see if you get a BIOS display.

Comment: While it seems obvious, I don't see any mention of Antivirus usage here, have you tried virus scanning and automated removal from the likes of Avast or AVG? - (google those names to find those antivirus programs).

Comment: @Sam3000 That was the first thing I tried but the malware hogs so much CPU usage that the scan was going very very slow.

Comment: Okay, when you say it hog's a lot of the cpu what process is it shown as in task manager?

Comment: @Sam3000 If I remember correctly it spawned hundreds of process's that all had different names, most of which were things like `gamehelper` or `social2google`. Right now I'm removing my hard drive and video card and trying to reset my BIOS settings to see if I can atleast boot into the BIOS settings so that I can reinstall windows from a USB drive.

Comment: Ah I see, well what you're doing is a good idea, feel free to come back if you need anything else

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I reset the BIOS settings by removing the the CMOS battery and putting it back and I also disconnected my hard drive, video card, keyboard and mouse and plugged my monitor into the integrated graphics from the CPU, but I am still not getting any video. This just seems very weird, I find it very unlikely that malware could affect things like the BIOS and the POST process.